# Appropriate distributions for infrequent events with copycats

Tags: mixed-model, poisson-distribution

I know that infrequent events, especially disasters like earthquakes, can often be modeled by the Poisson distribution. I was thinking of recent events like the Boston bombing and the ricin envelope; these events are infrequent disasters, but aren't independent of past events, because of copycats.

What are some good distributions that model infrequent copycat behavior? I imagine that events would come in "packets" with a Poisson distribution, but the size of each packet of events would vary some other way, e.g. a normal distribution. Is there any research on "copycat" disasters?

Comment: Doesn't the very concept of "copycat" suggest you should be using a more appropriate model than a mere (univariate) distribution?  Why not incorporate elements of the process in your model, such as modeling the original events and including a conditional model for the copycat events?  Use that to direct your exploratory analysis of your data to see what models it might suggest.

Answer (score 6):

Negative binomial distributions are often used in cases where there is contagion among events in the *same* time period. Contagion across time periods can be incorporated by using the lagged outcomes as an explanatory variable. See Gary King, *Unifying Political Methodology* for more detail. So-called Zero-Inflated Negative Binomial models, as the name suggest, incorporate models where there are a number of "zero" observations.

Comment: Similar to the zip, hurdle models have been suggested as well. See Porter & White [*SELF-EXCITING HURDLE MODELS FOR TERRORIST ACTIVITY*](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1203.3680.pdf)